# REACT-HOOKS: How do I store a modifed parameter made by the user?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I have checkboxes and I want to save in useState hooks the modified value made by the user. By default the current state is fixed and the checkbox is filled if `my_value === 1, elif 0 unfilled`. But if my user decides to uncheck it, how can I store this action. (if unchecked the value is 0).

Same idea with dropdown, the default value is fixed. The user can change the `Taste`( `Good/Medium/Bad`)or the `Comments` (`(0/4....4/4)`).
For now I get only the current state.

```
export default function Display() {
    ...
    //For my checkboxes 
    const [availability, setAvailability] = useState(item.values[0].availability)
    ...
    const [trust, setTrust] = useState(item.values[0].trust)

    //For my dropdowns 
    const [taste, setTaste] = useState(item.taste)
    ...
    const [comments, setComments] = useState(rule.comments)

    function Checkbox({ value }) {
        const [checked, setChecked] = useState(value);

        return (
            <label>
                <input
                    type="checkbox"
                    checked={checked}
                    onChange={() => setChecked(checked => !checked)}
                />
                {value}
            </label>
        );
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <div>
                Availability :  <Checkbox value={!!availability} />
            </div>
            ....           
            <div > 
                Taste : <Dropdown style={styles.select} options={TASTE} defaultValue={LIKELIHOOD.find((t) => t.label === item.taste)} />
            </div>
             ...
        </div >
    );
}
```

Comment: _"where do i store a modified parameter?_" **you don't**. it breaks two rules 1) don't modify parameters 2) don't copy parameters to state

Comment: so if I changed `Availibility` which is by default `1` (for instance) and the user  uncheck the checkbox, it means that now my `setAvailibity` is set to `0`. I can not retrieve this action ?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't so much a hooks problem as a "where do I store my state" problem. So far I don't see any place in your implementation to store the users choices. Either the MenuItemDisplay component needs to maintain that state, or it needs to receive it from a parent component. Either way, that state (containing user choices) will need to be passed down (along with update functions) into the checkbox component as the value of a 'checked' prop, and the update functions for that state should be passed as (and adapted to) the checkbox 'onToggle' (or similar) prop

Comment: If the user has unchecked `Availibility` which is by default `1` (for instance) it means that now my `setAvailibity` is set to `0`. I can not change the  `setAvailibity` status?